xsltproc gives warning: "failed to load external entity" and error "xsl:include : unable to load .." for xsl:include to HTTPS URL
I have a local stylesheet like the following, i.e. it has an xsl:include with a href attribute pointing to a https URL:
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

<xsl:include href="https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/foo-transform-module.xsl"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>

For me on three different systems xsltproc fails to process the local stylesheet (with e.g. xsltproc xslt-test1.xsl sample1.xml), giving me the a warning and an error:
warning: failed to load external entity "https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/foo-transform-module.xsl"
compilation error: file xslt-test1.xsl line 3 element include
xsl:include : unable to load https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt/foo-transform-module.xsl

Other XSLT processors seem to be able to find and load the included stylesheet and output e.g.
<root>
  <transformed-foo>foo 1</transformed-foo>
  <bar>bar 1</bar>
</root>

for an input sample1.xml like
<root>
  <foo>foo 1</foo>
  <bar>bar 1</bar>
</root>

I have looked through the options of xsltproc but I only find an option --nonet to disallow loading external entities, I don't see any default that would explain why the HTTPS access fails.
Can anyone reproduce this problem or, if not, tell me which setting I need so that xsltproc loads the included XSLT module?

I am seeing the same problem.

@nwellnhof, can you tell whether that is a quirk or bug in xsltproc/libxslt?

It seems using libxslt in Python with lxml I can use urllib3 or some of the request libs to implement a Resolver to have better support for HTTP(S) URLs. Still not sure whether the failure described in the question is some security based restriction in xsltproc/libxslt that can be changed by some configuration or whether I wrongly assume resolving HTTP(S?) URLs should work.

Some processors might refuse to load external stylesheets. Others require it to be enabled with a flag. This is done for security reasons.

@DJL, any specific insight as to what is the setting or what are the settings for xsltproc? It has a --nonet option documented as refuse to fetch DTDs or entities over network but it is not clear to me why it fails to load over HTTP(S) if that option is not used. That security reasons these days often means that resolving external files is by default disabled is no news to me, happens for instance with MSXML 6 by default but is has a property I can set to true (e.g. resolveExternals = true).

@MartinHonnen tbh i'm not familiar with xsltproc and as such the advice was generic. however i will point out that your included xslt file is neither a DTD nor an entity (nor a document). Have you tried using the verbose flag?

@DJL, yes, I have also tried verbose but as far as I could tell it didn't give any more details as to why the loading of the XSLT module failed, it spewed out a lot of more details but the three lines I show in the question seemed to remain the only three lines related to the failure to load the XSLT module. No idea really why you consider an included XSLT file to be no entity nor a document, any well-formed XSLT stylesheet is a well-formed XML document.

@MartinHonnen An entity is specifically declared as follows: <!ENTITY name "value">.
And while you're right that an xslt can be treated as a document, in the xslt context it is specifically loaded with the document function

@DJL, that is a pretty limited definition of both entity and document that I don't share. And do notice that xsltproc gives an error "failed to load external entity".

@MartinHonnen - I don't know what else to tell you.

@DJL, I would suggest you read the spec https://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-physical-struct: "[Definition: An XML document may consist of one or many storage units. These are called entities; they all have content and are all (except for the document entity and the external DTD subset) identified by entity name.] Each XML document has one entity called the document entity, which serves as the starting point for the XML processor and may contain the whole document." to get a better understanding of what is an entity or a document.

It appears, that according to https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/libxml2/-/blob/master/README.md, there are various build options for libxml/libxslt whether to include modules, one of them being --with-http HTTP support (off) where I assume off indicates that the default setting is to not include HTTP support.
I think that explains it, all the installations I tried (xsltproc package under various WSL Ubuntu Linux editions) have probably been built with that default setting and therefore without HTTP support.
